# Keeping track of user votes (one vote per topic i.e Reddit)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an application which allows users to influence player rankings and trends on a live board (fantasy football).

[image]

As you can see, you can upvote, or downvote players (only if you are logged in and authenticated via Firebase (Google accounts)). Otherwise, if you aren't logged in, no vote registers. That is currently working fine.

**My question is**, what would be the easiest way to have each user only be able to vote on a player ***once***. The current implementation allows unlimited up or down votes for any player. I would like it so I can upvote Tom Brady, but not upvote him again. From that point, I could only change it to no vote (by clicking up again) or downvote. I see there are User UID's in firebase, so I could check to see if the UserUID has voted on the specific player in the firebase DB or not before allowing the vote to go through, but what if the user just wants to change from an up vote to a down vote?

Here's the code which deals with voting --

```
downvotePlayer(playerId) {

this.state.user ?
  this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {
    if (player) {
      player.votes--
    }
    return player;
  })
  :
  console.log("Must log in to vote")

}

upvotePlayer(playerId) {
this.state.user ?
  this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {
    if (player) {
      console.log(player)
      player.votes++
    }
    return player;
  })
  :
  console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")

}
```

Here's the layout on Firebase:

[image]

If I left anything critical out, please let me know and I'll throw it in a gist. Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**

Initial DB ref is

```
    this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('players');
```

When adding an upvote to a player, I'm doing this:

```
    this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {

    if (player) {
      var ref = firebase.database().ref('players').child('voters');
      ref.child(uid).set(1);
    }
```

Which is doing almost what it needs to, except it's creating a new node all together in firebase.

[image]

The "voters" should be inside of the unique player above it. Is my issue obvious? I appreciate the help sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to model this is to store a single counter per player per "things they can vote on". For example:

```
"Votes": {
  "Tom Brady": {
    "uidOfVoter1": 1,
    "uidOfVoter2": -1
  }
}
```

The `uidOfVoter` values are the unique that you give each player, i.e. the UID they get from Firebase Authentication. In a structure like this, each UID can be present only once. You then ensure that each user can only write their own vote, with Firebase security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Votes": {
      "$thing": {
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".validate": "data.isNumber() && data.val() >= -1 && data.val() <= 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now to get the total votes, either:

- Download the votes and count them on the client.
- Update a counter whenever a user votes, writing security rules to ensure that the vote they write and the count are matching.
- Use a Cloud Functions to update the count whenever a vote is cast/changed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly. Every time a user votes on say .. Tom Brady, firebase will add a field under Brady with their ID and it will be either a -1, or 1? [Imgur Example](https://imgur.com/a/d81mE). If so, I can see how this would be easy to make sure the person can only vote once per player.

Comment: You will have to write the code for all of this: when a user casts a vote (up, neutral or negative) you write that into the database. But with this structure and rules, they can only ever write one vote per user per "things to vote on".

Comment: I'm having luck currently accessing the UIDs of the voters now. One thing I'm stuck on is how to structure the firebase data. Currently when I add a new player to the database, it is pushed as so: `this.database.push().set({ playerContent: playerName, votes: 0 })` How would I structure things so something I'm pushing can have child nodes? Such as `this.database.push().set({ playerContent: playerName, votes: 0, voters })` and have it structure as so: https://imgur.com/a/PncJ1 (The first image is how it is currently pushing.)

Comment: Calling `push()` generates a new node every time, which makes it hard to control the number of votes someone can cast. So instead of calling `push`, use `child(uid)` to set the one vote for that player.

Comment: I updated the original post with an edit. I think it's close. It's setting the UID to the database with a 1 if an upvote is cast, it is just not putting it in the correct spot. I have been looking at the docs for set and transaction and think I'm just a little off. I included the code and image of what it's producing in the edit above. Thanks for the help sir.

Answer (score 4):

Boolean. + is true and - is false. The existence of the UID indicates a vote(r).

I can't speak to coding react specifically, but it seems that this would be the most simple (best) way to represent what you are after.

Disable/grey-out the respective vote button on the client UI once they vote either way. Even if they hack the UI, server-side (db side) it's a boolean so you can't true true it for +2.

```
DB Structure
thing
  votes
    <uid1>:true,
    <uid2>:true,
    <uid3>:false,
```

If user undoes vote, simply delete the uid from the thing they voted on.